# PhantomJS capturing screenshot of mobile browser

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, screenshot

I was trying to create a web screenshot with PhantomJS, but I am getting the image as mobile browser. I am using MAC OS Yosemite. Here is my JavaScript:

screen.js

```
var WebPage = require('webpage');
page = WebPage.create();
page.open('http://www.apple.com');
page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        page.render('appleScreenShot' + '.png');
        phantom.exit();
    }, 2000);
}
```

And here is my command line code

```
phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --web-security=false --ssl-protocol=tlsv1 --debug=true screen.js
```

Answer (score 7):

You may find that you need to specify a [`viewportSize`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html) (and perhaps even [`zoomFactor`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/zoom-factor.html)) for certain websites depending on the media queries specified within their resources.

From the documentation on `viewportSize`:

> Because PhantomJS is headless (nothing is shown), viewportSize
>   effectively simulates the size of the window like in a traditional
>   browser.

Example usages:

```
page.viewportSize = {
    width: 1280,
    height: 800
};
page.zoomFactor = 1; //default value is 1
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. Setting page.viewportSize helped me. I used the max resolution. page.viewportSize = { width: 1600, height: 1200 };

Comment: please can you mark that question as an correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to add the background color rendering, because the default will be a transparent background.

```
page.evaluate(function() {
    document.body.bgColor = 'white';
});
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

You can use NightmareJs with node :

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: false })
nightmare
  .useragent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36')
  .viewport(1200, 1800)
  .wait()
  .goto('url...')
  .wait()
  .screenshot('image.png')
  .end()
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log('page done');
 })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
 })
```

I found it was easier to use for screenshots than PhantomJs

Answer (score -1):

In Java I change User Agent string. It works for me.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.41 Safari/535.1";
 capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_PAGE_SETTINGS_PREFIX + "userAgent", userAgent);
            driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
```